# DataSource in WAS7 and Oracle DB Kerberos

Tags: oracle, kerberos, websphere-7

I've got user in Oracle DB which is created as "identified externally" and logs in via Kerberos. Is it possible to configure WAS7 DataSource to establish connection under this user?

When user in Oracle is created as "identified by password" there is no problems, I just create in WAS7 JAAS J2C Authentification Data and set it as "Component-managed authentification alias".